# The server does not accept clients after several reboots

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, client-server, boost-asio

I'm writing a small server, which can parse XML files and send pieces of information to the clients (OS Windows Server 2008 R2).

**SERVER**

For passing **io_service** as a parameter to the methods, I use **boost::shared_ptr**:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<io_service> service_ptr;
...
_service_ptr = boost::make_shared<io_service>();
```

Clients accepting thread:

```
void accept_thread(ServerConfig const& config) {
    try {
        while(!_data_.IsValid()) {
            std::cout << "Wait for complete data..." << std::endl;
            boost::this_thread::sleep( millisec(500));
        }

        while (true) {
            _pool.WaitNewClient(_service_ptr);
        }
    } catch(std::exception& e) {
        LOG::Write(LOG_ERR, std::string("In Accept thread: ") + e.what());
        std::cerr << "In Accept thread: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Accepting next client:

```
void CClientPool::WaitNewClient(service_ptr& serv_ptr) {
    client_ptr new_( new talk_to_client(serv_ptr));
    _acceptor.Accept(new_);

    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(*_mutex);// safe lock for clients
    new_->reset_last_ping();
    clients.push_back(new_);
    LOG::Write(LOG_INF, "Connected new client.");
    std::cout << "Connected new client." << std::endl;
}
```

And:

```
void CClientAcceptor::Init(int port, service_ptr& serv_ptr) {
    acceptor_ptr_ = boost::make_shared<ip::tcp::acceptor>(*serv_ptr, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), port) ); 
}

void CClientAcceptor::Accept(client_ptr& cl_ptr) {
    acceptor_ptr_->accept( cl_ptr->sock());
}
```

,where **acceptor_ptr_**:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<ip::tcp::acceptor> acceptor_ptr;
...
acceptor_ptr acceptor_ptr_;
```

**CLIENT**

```
void connect(std::string const& host, int port, boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service>& service) {

    if(connected_){
        disconnect();
    }
    sock_.reset(new ip::tcp::socket(*service));
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    ep = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string(host), port);

    // do while not connection
    int attempt = 0;
    do {
        if(attempt++ > 0) {
            std::cerr << "attempt reconnect #" << attempt << "..." << std::endl;
        }

        sock_->connect(ep, ec);
        if(ec){
            std::cerr << "Failed connection to server: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(1000));
        }
    } while(ec);

    connected_ = true; 
}

void disconnect() {
    if(sock_) {
        boost::system::error_code errorcode;

        if(sock_->is_open()) {
            sock_->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, errorcode);
            if (errorcode) {
                std::cerr << "socket.shutdown error: " << errorcode.message() << std::endl;
            }

            sock_->close(errorcode);
            if (errorcode) {
                std::cerr << "socket.close error: " << errorcode.message() << std::endl;
            }
        }
        sock_.reset();
    }

    connected_ = false;
}
```

When I debug the program (starting and stopping the server/clients), there is a point when the server stops accepting clients. While connecting the client runs without errors, the server does not accept the client anymore. After changing the port the problem disappears. What could be the problem?

Comment: Since you fail to check for errors from `accept` I would guess you didn't check `bind` either.